# Нужен совет от опытного разработчика по парсингу ресурса

Tags: php, java, jsoup, парсер

Добрый день. Имеется большой опыт в написании парсеров на php. Вопрос, собственно, вот в чем: есть один громадный парсер, и встал вопрос оптимизации скорости. Есть ли смысл переписывать парсер на java (например, используя что-то вроде jsoup)? Каков в этом случае будет прирост скорости?

Вопрос конкретнее: будет ли существенно отличаться скорость работы 2-х парсеров одного и того же ресурса, находящихся на одном и том же сервере, если один написан на java, а другой на php (сервер отличный, dedicated)? Java изучаю, но нет большого опыта в этом вопросе.

Comment: а Вы уже профайлером бегали и узнали, что узкое место, это php, а не сеть?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Разрабатываю парсеры разной сложности на Java используя JSOUP. Думаю если распараллелить процесс парсинга, то прироста в скорости можно достигнуть!

Comment: А вы точно уверены, что есть вообще смысл оптимизировать именно парсер? Прежде чем что-либо оптимизировать нужно убедиться, что проблема именно в нём, иначе это не имеет смысла. "Излишняя оптимизация - корень всех бед."

Comment: Рекомендую переформулировать вопрос в "как профилировать/оптимизировать производительность парсера". Тогда можно будет дать конкретные ответы, которые позволят вам понять, где узкое место и - следовательно - каким инструментом с ним работать. KoVadim прав, что переносит фокус обсуждения с инструмента на задачу.

Comment: А в текущей формулировке вопрос предполагает обмен субъективными мнениями, такой формат - оффтопик для SO. После правки вопрос будет переоткрыт и на него можно будет дать ответ. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: да, тупо из-а многопоточности

Comment: @Etki, что-то у меня сомнения, что парсеру нужна многопоточность.

Comment: @Qwertiy для ускорения конечно не нужна. Десять-двадцать-сорок раз - это же ведь все еще то же самое O(n) в теории алгоритмов.